# Issues after running flutter doctor

Tags: android, flutter, execute

I'm new to flutter so I'm terribly sorry if this question is too basic.

I came up with a flutter project in iOS and am currently trying to continue coding it in windows 10 but when I ran flutter doctor, I received the result below:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1;\bin\java to determine the version

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[!] Android Studio (not installed)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)

[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

I don't have an idea how to go with the first issue. With the second, I have an Android Studio installed from which I am able to open the app from an emulator.

Could anyone help guide on how to process the two issues, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

for windows, change your JAVA_HOME path, in pc propierties(right click my pc), enviromental variables, to android studio installation  path, in my case:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

open new cmd window to test flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

Install Andriod studio again and while installing select the android toolchain option so it will get installed and then set the path of the android SDK after installing android studio.This will solve the android studio not being detected part and then you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to avoid reinstall doing the other suggestions but I ended up reinstalling. It resolved the mentioned issues but brought some other complications. I'll just open another discussion for the new errors. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the JDK in windows. Reinstall the JDK and set the Environment Variable path. If the problem persists again, try to use JDK 11.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this and was able to get the latest JDK. I did the Environment Variable path settings too but it didn't solve the issue. I understood that JDK was the latest stable version but I didn't try to download it anymore because I realized I still had a working JDK which made my past projects in the same PC work on the emulator. I ended up uninstalling and re-installing android studio again.

Comment: It did solve the 2 issues mentioned but it caused more new errors and this time, the emulator don't run anymore. I won't elaborate further and will just go open a new inquiry about it to avoid complications on this thread,

Comment: Can you share the JDK version you are using?

Comment: My current android studio's using jdk15. I was advised to download 16 so I did but it's still working on 15 so I didn't bother change. I still have both 15 and 16 installed.

Comment: As the problem is related to flutter, that means the environment is not set up properly. And one more thing, your previous projects are ok with the current JDK setup doesn't mean it will also be ok with flutter. It's better to have a clean setup for flutter.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the same too which is why I reinstalled. I want to close this thread now since the issue was resolved. Sorry for asking but do you know how to mark this issue resolved? I 'M just new to using stackoverflow and am trying but can not find such buttons.